# which node.js is needed for Ionic V1.4.3

Tags: node.js, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to use Ionic V1.X, since I want to use AngularJS with .js support, instead of Angular with .ts support.

But when I try to run "ionic -v" to see my ionic version it prints out:

```
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
 at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)


at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
 at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
 at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
 at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
 at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
 at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\tubes\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules
aceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:3:27)
 at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
```

I deinstalled my previous ionic version to reinstall the old one.
I saw online that I could need an older node.js version, but I cannot find which one is needed.
my actual node.js is v12.19.0

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tried out different node.js
node.js V.6.12.3 seems to work, for anyone who might encounter the same problem